How does "suggest transaction" permission work?
I'm kinda new in Blockchain development. I've been looking at how dApps work and I want to figure out how the permissions are given to the dApp. I understand that when a wallet connects to a dApp, it gives permission to read Public Key, account balance, activity and suggest transactions to approve.
The first 3 are simple to understand from the dApps perspective. But how does the dApp actually suggests transactions for the user to approve and the user is notified through Metamask? Is it some JavaScript code in the frontend, some library that works for every wallet, or is this code inside the smart contract of the dApp?
Thank you in advance.

Great question! There are many libraries for a variety of languages that developers can use to connect to wallets, such as Metmask, and interact with smart contracts. To do this, you must supply certain configurations, such as a chain ID and RPC URL. (Viem/WAGMI maintains a list of default RPC URLs, enabling you to exclude one from your code, although this is not recommended).
import { createWalletClient, custom } from 'viem'
import { mainnet } from 'viem/chains'

const client = createWalletClient({
  chain: mainnet,
  transport: custom(window.ethereum)
})

For example, a popular Javascript/Typescript library called Viem can be used to send data to an Ethereum node in the blockchain in a way that is developer-friendly. The documentation is extremely thorough and descriptive, if you want to read data from a smart contract without changing state, you can use public clients and the readContract method. If you want to interact with a non-view function, e.g. when transferring tokens with ERC20 transfer(), you can use a wallet client and the write contract method.

Finally, as I'm sure you and anyone who has spent time on web3 dapps are aware, there is always a "connect button". Usually, they are on the site's header, but obviously, that is simply convention, developers can turn any button into one that connects to any wallet extension as long as the library supports it. A popular react library called Rainbowkit makes this process fairly straightforward and like Viem, has very thorough documentation.
<RainbowButton.Custom>
  {({ ready, connect }) => {
    return (
      <button
        type="button"
        disabled={!ready}
        onClick={connect}
      >
        Connect Rainbow
      </button>
    );
  }}
</RainbowButton.Custom>

